# Jenkins : How to run Android Espresso tests on Jenkins in emulator

Tags: jenkins, android-espresso

I have written espresso tests for my application and now I want to run these tests under Jenkins using the emulator.

How can I configure Jenkins to do this?

Comment: Slides about how someone else done this :: http://www.slideshare.net/SylwesterMadej/droidcon-hr